# Reading different parts of file in different functions - C++

Tags: c++

I've run into a bit of an issue on a programming assignment I'm working on. The background of the assignment is not needed for the question, so I'm gonna leave it out. Only thing possibly needed is that it's based around learning hash tables and general hashing strategies.

My question: I have to read input from a file, then using the first 3 lines of the file open 3 other files. After that, I need to read in however many queries I need to run (insert(), search(), delete(), etc.). Then run them and print the results at the end.

Opening the different files and hashing into tables is fine. I've done all of that in a function I created called loadfile().

I'm wondering if there's a way to open the same file in a different function, but have it pick up reading from where it left off previously (after the first 3 lines are read)? I want to get the queries in a line-by-line way so I can essentially process an indeterminate amount of queries, rather than just loading them in a vector and processing from there.

Right now my current strategy is to read the first 3 lines, throw them away, then continue reading. While this works, I was wondering if there was another way so I don't have to waste time throwing away lines or waste memory with a vector (if I don't have to).

Comment: Do you need to close the original file in between? If you keep it open the position will be kept, and you can resume reading from it later in the program.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if I keep it open in loadfile() (called in main() ), then call processQueries() (also called in main() ), can i use the same ifstream? Or would I need to pass a pointer between all of these functions to be able to do it properly?

EDIT: loadfile() is where I originally open the file.

Comment: Perhaps open the file in `main` and pass a reference to the stream to the functions that need it? Or, if the file isn't to big, read *all* of it at once into a buffer (or a vector of "lines"), and then use the buffer as and when needed?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I literally had that idea after I posted my comment. I think that's the best solution for what I want to do. Thank you!

EDIT: The file I have isn't large, but I don't know what size test files my instructor will be using, so I'd rather try and generalize it,  than arbitrarily fill an vector, etc.

Comment: Can you use a singleton design pattern if you don't want to read everything all at once. This is one of the cases where a singleton pattern is useful: you can open the file once and can keep track of current read location.